# tableview Cell separator line not showing in ios development using swift 2.0. xcode 7

Tags: uitableview, swift2, xcode7, xcode7.1

I am trying to make an ios app which has tableview in it.
When I was developing using xcode 7.0.1 it was showing tableview cells separator line Black thin line.
After I updated with Xcode 7.1.1 , its not showing cell separator lines.

I tried 3 things like -

- Tried All the settings in the right panel of xcode to show cell
  separator line.
- Tried setting up the Cell Line Separator using code in DidLoad method
- creating new SingleViewApp as well, in that also its not coming. Nothing solves the issue.

I believe either its bug in xcode 7.1.1 or I am done some wrong global settings in xcode, Because for new apps also its not showing.

Please suggest me some solution.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot here ?

Comment: Using SingleViewApp template, I have added `UITableView` on the Storyboard's root ViewController, applied edge-to-edge constraints, added a `UITableViewCell` onto table view, build and run in iPhone 6s Plus simulator and separators are there. Make sure you are seeing 100% simulator scale Window-> Scale->100% or Cmd+1

Comment: Can u check whether have you added a UITableViewController

Comment: Window->Scale->100% solves the problem, Actually my mistake was I was not seeing 100% in simulator. Thanks Eugene and Dimuth for your effort.

Answer (score 27):

It is possibly a bug when your simulator is scaled to 50% . I scaled the simulator window to 75% (CMD+2) or 100% (CMD+1) and that seems to show the separator lines.

Comment: yes simon you seems to right, might be a bug in xcode simulator, because before updating from 7.0.1 to 7.1.1, it was showing separator line even at 50%.

Comment: It might have to do with the resolution on older macbook screens being too low to render the separation, thanks for the tip

Comment: this happened with me when I was using my simulator on my macbook pro (iPhone X)